# Unable to trigger override method

Tags: java, android, inheritance, interface, fragment

I have a interface which has one method called drawCharts(), I have one `BaseFragmentClass` which implements this interface, Now I declared one more `ChildFrgament` class which is extending `BaseFragmentClass`, I tried to override drawCharts() method in `ChildFragment` class, but it is not at all triggered. Below is my code snippet

```
interface IDraw{
  public void drawCharts();
} 

public class BaseFragment extends Fragment implements IDraw {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawCharts(){
    }
}

public class ChildFragment extends BaseFragment{

    @Override
    public void drawCharts(){
      // have some stuff to execute
      // but not able to trigger
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it `onDraw()` or `drawCharts()`?

Comment: @MikeM. Edited my question

Comment: How do you try to trigger this method?

Comment: @Orlangure Trigger from where? can't be called automatically as its extending BaseFragment class

Comment: Methods don't get triggered just because they are declared in a parent, you should call them from somewhere

Comment: @Orlangure right now what I am doing is Inside Activity class I am adding ChildFragment which show up the ChildFragment Class, once the child fragment class shows up, I want to trigger this method to execute

Answer (score 0):

Methods don't get triggered just because they are declared in a parent, you should call them from somewhere.

In the following example you call this method after some button was clicked:

```
interface IDraw {
    public void drawCharts();
} 

public class BaseFragment extends Fragment implements IDraw {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    // this method is triggered by a click on a button
    public void onDrawButtonClick(View v) {
        // this will call a method implemented by a particular fragment - a child
        drawCharts();
    }

    @Override
    public void drawCharts() {

    }
}

public class ChildFragment extends BaseFragment {
    @Override
    public void drawCharts(){
      // have some stuff to execute
      // but not able to trigger
    }
}
```

You may as well try to trigger this method from parent's `onCreateView` or `onResume` methods, depends on what you need to do. Java will ensure that the method is called from an actual class and not from a parent.